# AngularJS find address using getaddress.io

Tags: angularjs

So I am trying to build a form that has a find address button which calls an API.
I am using https://getaddress.io/ to try to do this (because it seemed the most straight forward to use).

So I have included their script on my page:

```
<script src="https://getaddress.io/js/jquery.getAddress-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

and I have created a field like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : saveForm.postCode.$invalid && !saveForm.postCode.$pristine }">
    <label class="sr-only">Post code</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="postCode" name="postCode" placeholder="Post code" ng-model="controller.customer.postCode" required />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" address-finder="postCode">Find</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and tried to build my directive like this:

```
.directive('addressFinder', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            targetElementId: '=addressFinder'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Get our target element
            var target = angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.targetElementId));

            // If we have a target
            if (target) {

                // Bind a function to the click event
                element.bind('click', function () {

                    // Create our options
                    var options = {
                        api_key: '<valid_api_key>',
                        onLookupSuccess: function (data) {

                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    };

                    // Call the targets function
                    target.getAddress(options);
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```

but when I press the button I get an error stating that getAddress is not a function.
Does anyone know how I can get this to work?